# Matplotlib: draw grid lines behind other graph elements

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

In Matplotlib, I make dashed grid lines as follows:

```
fig = pylab.figure()    
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
```

however, I can't find out how (or even if it is possible) to make the grid lines be drawn behind other graph elements, such as bars. Changing the order of adding the grid versus adding other elements makes no difference.

Is it possible to make it so that the grid lines appear behind everything else?

Comment: `ax.set_axisbelow(True)` still works. Also nice for pdf output...

Comment: I would have expected ``ax.set_axisbelow(True)`` to be the default...

Answer (score 197, accepted):

According to this - http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/axis-elements-and-zorder-td5346.html - you can use `Axis.set_axisbelow(True)`

(I am currently installing matplotlib for the first time, so have no idea if that's correct - I just found it by googling "matplotlib z order grid" - "z order" is typically used to describe this kind of thing (z being the axis "out of the page"))

Comment: Is it possible to have the gridlines below the bar/line while retaining the labels on top? I also posted this quesiton separately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522447/in-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-set-gridlines-below-bars-lines-patches-while-re

Comment: It might be this http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/axis-elements-and-zorder-td5346.html, ancient thread though.

Answer (score 153):

To me, it was unclear how to apply andrew cooke's answer, so this is a complete solution based on that:

```
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
```

Comment: Very nice, works like a charme, here!

Comment: As of June 2023 this is the only answer that has worked for me. Setting zorders to 0 or even negative for the grid and high for the plot element hasn't worked.

Answer (score 79):

If you want to validate the setting for **all** figures, you may set

```
plt.rc('axes', axisbelow=True)
```

or

```
plt.rcParams['axes.axisbelow'] = True
```

It works for Matplotlib>=2.0.

Comment: Best answer, since people will likely want this to be consistent across all figures.

Comment: Make sure to put `plt.grid()` (or modified) after `plt.rc('axes', axisbelow=True)`.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and the following worked:

```
[line.set_zorder(3) for line in ax.lines]
fig.show() # to update
```

Increase `3`to a higher value if it does not work.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set the `zorder` kwarg in `matplotlib.pyplot.grid`

```
plt.grid(which='major', axis='y', zorder=-1.0)
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo you have to set the `zorder` also on everything else that gets painted.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure the points have a higher zorder value than the gridlines, e.g.:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,c="k",marker="x",zorder=2)
```

followed by

```
plt.grid(linestyle="--",alpha=0.5,zorder=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use one of Seaborn's styles. For instance:

```
import seaborn as sns  
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
```

Not only the gridlines will get behind but the looks are nicer.

Answer (score 1):

For some (like me) it might be interesting to draw the grid behind only "some" of the other elements. For granular control of the draw order, you can use [matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) on the axes directly:

```
ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax.set_zorder(3)
```

This is mentioned in the notes on [matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html?highlight=grid#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid).

Answer (score 0):

These answers weren't working for me (`zorder`, `axisbelow`, `set_zorder`):

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, dpi=200)
ax[0].yaxis.grid(True, which='major', linestyle='--')
ax[0].boxplot(data, positions=[0, 0.5], widths=[0.5, 0.5])
```

Instead, changing the background color of the graph elements using `patch_artist` worked for me:

```
l = ax[0].boxplot(data, positions=[0, 0.5], widths=[0.5, 0.5],
  patch_artist=True)
for bplot in (l,):
  for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], ['white', 'white']):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

ax.grid(color='grey', alpha=0.2)

set the transparency of gridlines to low using alpha=0.2
this might make the gridlines appear behind the actual graph