# How to draw grid lines behind matplotlib bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x = ['01-02', '02-02', '03-02', '04-02', '05-02']
y = [2, 2, 3, 7, 2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.bar(range(len(y)), y, width=0.3,align='center',color='skyblue')
plt.xticks(range(len(y)), x, size='small')
plt.savefig('/home/user/graphimages/foo2.png')
plt.close()
```

I want to draw grid lines (of x & y) behind the bar graph.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

To add a grid you simply need to add

`ax.grid()`

If you want the grid to be behind the bars then add

```
ax.grid(zorder=0)
ax.bar(range(len(y)), y, width=0.3, align='center', color='skyblue', zorder=3)
```

The important part is that the `zorder` of the bars is greater than grid. Experimenting it seems `zorder=3` is the lowest value that actually gives the desired effect. I have no idea why `zorder=1` isn't sufficient.

**EDIT**: 
I have noticed this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726391/matplotlib-draw-grid-lines-behind-other-graph-elements) using a different method although it suffers some link rot. Both methods yield the same result as far as I can see but andrew cooke's answer is more elegant.

Comment: Though not part of this problem, it may be good to note that this solution will not work if there are error bars specified through the `yerr` or `xerr` (the filled bar will obscure them); using `ax.set_axisbelow()` does work for this case.

Comment: As noted above this does not work with error bars. For completeness, the command `ax.set_axisbelow()` needs a true statement, as `ax.set_axisbelow(True)`.

Comment: What if I'm using `ax.yaxis.grid(True)` to show only horizontal grid? adding `ax.grid(zorder=0)` will make vertical grid show up.

Comment: maybe the figure face is at zorder==0 and the axes face is at zorder==1?  Didn't test the theory.

Comment: this link worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726391/matplotlib-draw-grid-lines-behind-other-graph-elements , the approach with zorder didn't

Comment: It appears that setting the zorder of the bars is what matters. I can set the zorder of the bars to 2, and the zorder of the grid to 100, but the bars still appear over the grid. I don't understand this behavior. I've actually tried several numbers from -1 to 100, and all I've tried work when bar zorder=2.

Answer (score 26):

I am suggesting another solution since the most voted answer did not work for me. You can use the following code to set the gridlines behind the plot.

```
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
```

I got this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39039520/8541242).

Answer (score 3):

```
plt.grid(True, color = "grey", linewidth = "1.4", linestyle = "-.")
```

This worked for me, the grid lines will be in grey border color,if you want can change border design to `linestyle = ".."`
Like this

```
plt.grid(True, color = "grey", linewidth = "1.4", linestyle = "..")
```

Summing up entire code block:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.bar(range(len(y)), y, width=0.3,align='center',color='skyblue')
plt.xticks(range(len(y)), x, size='small')
plt.grid(True, color = "grey", linewidth = "1.4", linestyle = "-.")
plt.savefig('/home/user/graphimages/foo2.png')
plt.close()
```

Comment: `ValueError: '..' is not a valid value for ls; supported values are '-', '--', '-.', ':', 'None', ' ', '', 'solid', 'dashed', 'dashdot', 'dotted'`

Answer (score 0):

use `.grid()` it makes the order go to 0 (back)

```
ax.grid(zorder=0)
```

Answer (score -4):

ax.grid(zorder=0) Woud work. But First Place the Bar and then Place the Grid.Not the orther way.

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x='Index', y='Values', rot=90)
ax.grid(zorder=0)
```

I took some currency Correlation with Year and Sorted it as my Data Frame df, and below is the result of the code run. 
[image: I took some currency Correlation with Year and Sorted it as my Data Frame df]

Comment: the gridlines all seem to be _over_ the bars, not behind.