# Matplotlib: draw grid behind everything else

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Given the following example code, which draws an ellipse, how can I make the grid lines appear behind everything else?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
grid()
ax.add_artist( Ellipse( xy = (0,0), width = 1, height = 2, angle = 0, edgecolor='b', lw=4, facecolor='green' ) )
show()
```

The answers on this website to similar questions haven't worked in my case. Can you give a complete working example?

Comment: ["pylab is deprecated and its use is strongly discouraged because of namespace pollution. Use pyplot instead."](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw grid lines behind matplotlib bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357798/how-to-draw-grid-lines-behind-matplotlib-bar-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize the `zorder` argument. Make this modification and it will work.

```
ax.add_artist( Ellipse( xy = (0,0), width = 1, height = 2, angle = 0, edgecolor='b', lw=4, facecolor='green' ,zorder=2) )
```

Anytime you are plotting multiple items, you can control the order they appear with `zorder`. Find more information on `zoder` [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html).

This simple fix makes the figure go from this:

[image: Grid in front]

to this:

[image: Grid behind]